# Android Java Sqlite Exception index 0 requested with size of 0

Tags: java, android

I think I understand what this error refers to. Basically as I understand it the cursor is empty. Which means the query is not finding any rows that equal its where statement.

The query is basically

> SELECT * FROM questions WHERE _id=2

Now the thing I don't understand is that if I user a database with 7 records it is fine then when I change it over to one with 100 it runs this exception. The odd thing is that from other parts of the app I output the entire databases contents referring to specific columns.

All the columns in both db's are called the same and when outputting everything from a table you can refer to everything. The problem seems to be when you query the large db specifically looking for one row. It returns empty.

Is there anything that would be doing this, like special characters or anything else I have over looked?

Comment: Does the larger db have a row with id = 2?

Comment: yep there sure is one with that id. There is a list view listing them all and when you click it they should display. There is also a view each sequentially and that is not working. So pages that are not using a WHERE clause are ok but ones with a WHERE clause are not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More code would be helpful.  The obvious thing to do is verify that your large database has the correct filename, tablename and _id column and that there is a row with _id=2.    Another thing I would try (probably not the problem) is to put quotes around the 2 -- WHERE _id='2'.

Comment: No idea why it has been working so far, but your suggestion to add the single quotes did the trick. Thank you. Much appreciated.

Comment: You bet, glad to be able to help out :)

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue in my app.  For me it was because my cursors were exceeding the VM object memory limit of 1mb.  This could be your issue.

Are you retrieving any blobs?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm not retrieving any blobs. I am retrieving all of the database in other parts of the app and they are working fine. odd!